# jaspersoft and mongoDb gridFs image

Tags: mongodb, jasper-reports, gridfs

I am currently developing reports in jaspersoft utilizing mongoDb in the background.  I have images uploaded to mongoDb gridFS and need to display these images on the reports out of the databases.

I've been successful in the past doing this out of SQL, but cannot get the images to render from mongoDb.

Does anyone have an experience displaying images out of gridFS on jaspersoft reports?

JRXML BELOW:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.1.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.1.0  -->
<!-- 2015-11-12T09:57:02 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="imageTest" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="a2bd4e02-ac58-4869-8bca-92fe8eff6d77">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="mongoLocal"/>
    <subDataset name="fileQuery" uuid="c420c8eb-8dad-4163-a067-fb1e783c7bfa">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="mongoLocal"/>
        <queryString language="MongoDbQuery">
            <![CDATA[{
    collectionName: 'studentImages.files',
    findQuery: { '_id' : { $oid : "55d74f02149c82ac5b615791" } }
}]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="_id" class="org.bson.types.ObjectId"/>
        <field name="chunkSize" class="java.lang.Long"/>
        <field name="contentType" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="filename" class="com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFSDBFile"/>
        <field name="length" class="java.lang.Long"/>
        <field name="md5" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="uploadDate" class="java.util.Date"/>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="MongoDbQuery">
        <![CDATA[{
    collectionName: 'fs.chunks',
    findQuery: { 'files_id' : { $oid : "5644a7d1eeb5ea4e43774267" } }
}]]>
```

Comment: Can you post your code if you have tried ?

Comment: I added my most recent attempt to the original question.

Comment: Is the problem in the query or displaying the file in jasper report?, what is your current value of filename?

Comment: The problem is the displaying of the image.  I'm adding an image to the report then the custom expression for that image is pointing to the data of gridFS.  It appears to have to do with the java class, I get an incorrect class error when ran.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to query in your MongoDbQuery, but if you manage to fill the filename (its not null) you can probably use the `getInputStream()` in the [GridFSDBFile API](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/gridfs/GridFSDBFile.html) to display the image in jasper report.

```
<image scaleImage="FillFrame" onErrorType="Blank">
   <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"/>
   <imageExpression class="java.io.InputStream"><![CDATA[$P{filename}.getInputStream()]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```